# Solve the following error message "Unclosed quotation mark after the character string"

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Below is the table I have created and inserted values in it:

```
CREATE TABLE prod_sales   
(saleID int identity(1,1),   
saleDate date,  
department varchar(125),   
amount int )  
GO   
  
INSERT INTO prod_sales VALUES   
('2016-01-01','Men''s Clothing & Accessories' ,ROUND(RAND() * 1000, 0)),  
('2016-01-02','Phones & Telecommunications',ROUND(RAND() * 1000, 0)),  
('2016-01-01','Computer & Office',ROUND(RAND() * 1000, 0)),  
('2016-01-02','Consumer Electronics',ROUND(RAND() * 1000, 0)),  
('2016-01-01','Men''s Clothing & Accessories' ,ROUND(RAND() * 1000, 0)),  
('2016-01-02','Phones & Telecommunications',ROUND(RAND() * 1000, 0)),  
('2016-01-01','Computer & Office',ROUND(RAND() * 1000, 0)),  
('2016-01-01','Consumer Electronics',ROUND(RAND() * 1000, 0)),  
('2016-01-01','Men''s Clothing Accessories' ,ROUND(RAND() * 1000, 0)),  
('2016-01-02','Phones & Telecommunications',ROUND(RAND() * 1000, 0)),  
('2016-01-02','Computer & Office',ROUND(RAND() * 1000, 0)),  
('2016-01-01','Consumer Electronics',ROUND(RAND() * 1000, 0))  
GO 

SELECT * FROM prod_sales
```

[image]

My aim is to to display the sum of sales, each day, for each of the various departments using **Dynamic PIVOT** and the query result should be something like which is shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

In order to achieve my aim, I have created a Stored Procedure for Dynamic PIVOT which is shown below:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE DynamicPivot
@ColumnToPivot VARCHAR(50),
@ListToPivot VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @SqlStatement VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SqlStatement =
'SELECT saleDate,[Computer & Office],[Consumer Electronics],[Men''s Clothing & Accessories],[Phones & Telecommunications]
FROM
(
 SELECT saleDate,department,amount
 FROM prod_sales
) AS DataSource
PIVOT
(
 SUM(amount)
 FOR ['+@ColumnToPivot+'] IN ('+@ListToPivot+')
) AS Pivoting'
EXECUTE (@SqlStatement)
END

EXECUTE DynamicPivot 'department','[Computer & Office],[Consumer Electronics],[Men''s Clothing & Accessories],[Phones & Telecommunications]'
```

The stored procedure was successfully created but after executing the stored procedure it is displaying an error message which is shown below:

[image]

How can this issue be fixed ?

Comment: Please don't use images for data or errors - use formatted text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the single quote, it's that you've set your string to 50 characters when you clearly need more than that:

```
@ListToPivot VARCHAR(50)
```

Try:

```
@ListToPivot varchar(4000)
```

Also why does the stored procedure hard-code the list of columns that you're passing in as a parameter? This fixes that too:

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8bc389ec816a8046df653b702cf26cdc)